# Unable to deploy shared printer through GPO

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I have a domain controller on which I have configured Print Management. I've added two printers:

- 192.168.0.98 => Students Printer => Share: //dc01/printer_students
- 192.168.0.99 => Teachers' Printer => Share: //dc01/printer_docenten

There's 2 domain local groups corresponding with both printers, which have access to each printer respectively.

---

I have configured a GPO like below, but the printer isn't visible when printing a document?

Running `gpresult /r` on the client shows that the gpo gets applied.

I've tried setting it to create instead of update, but without success.

Server: 2012 R2

Clients: Windows 10

**Update:** When I connect to the share of the printer by typing the share name into the file explorer once, then attempt to print a document again, it shows up fine (?).

Why is it doing that and how can I make it so that I don't have to connect to it once manually for it to show up?

---

[image]

Comment: Have you checked that the user can connect to the printer manually?  Have you waited long enough (4 hours) for the group policy to take effect?  Did the user log out and back in?

Comment: So, I have found that when I connect to the printer share once, then attempt to print a document again, the printer shows up fine! Also as default, which is what I need it to do. But why does it only do this when I manually connect to it once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the GPO click the common tab and click to run in user space/context. The GPO will wait more before running.

Make sure the driver is up to date too, as an incompability can cause the computer spooler to act badly

Comment: Thanks, it worked. This was driving me insane haha. Any reason to as why this has to be enabled? Was there insufficient time to apply the policy after start-up?

Comment: @rpm192 I think it’s because the GPO can run under the local system account, but as the printer got security modified, to allow only your security group, it fail to connect to it. The settings seem to force the GPO to impersonate the user.